# Mysqli_fetch_assoc loop not writing anything from the database

Tags: php, mysql

The point of this code is to write out comments on a post, so if the `Itemid` matches it will write it out beneath the post, but it's not writing anything.

```
$query2 = "select * from Comments inner join Items where Comments.Itemid = Items.Itemid order by date desc";
$result2 = mysqli_query($link, $query2);

while ($commentrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
  echo "<div class='svar'>";
  echo "<p> inlägg av:" . "<a href=profil.php?key=" . $commentrow['Userid'] . ">" . $commentrow['Name'] . "</a> " . " " . $commentrow['Date'] . "</p>";
  echo "<p>" . $commentrow['Item'] . "</p>";
}
```

Comment: I got it working date was ambigious and after inner join there should be on instead of where.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in your `INNER JOIN` replace `WHERE` with `ON`

```
$query2 = "select * from Comments inner join Items where Comments.Itemid = Items.Itemid order by date desc";
```

should be

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM Comments INNER JOIN Items ON Comments.Itemid = Items.Itemid ORDER BY date DESC";
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

**Alternate**

The way you are trying, can do without `INNER JOIN` like this with `WHERE` clause

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM Comments, Items WHERE Comments.Itemid = Items.Itemid ORDER BY date DESC";
```

SideNote: still in doubt about the query reason `ORDER BY date` because when you are fetching the data inside loop date is with capitol `Date` here `$commentrow['Date']`, which one is correct my guess should be `ORDER BY Date` and table name is missing, it should be `ORDER BY tablname.Date` where tablename can be `Comments` or `Items` depend which has the `Date` col